# Javascript - Subtracting Date and Time

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how to subtrack time. My #1 goal is to find out if a date and time has past the current date and time. I have posted another question on this but not have not got an answer or maybe i'm just not doing what they were telling me correctly.

I've been experimenting with this:

**Returned Value for Below script...**
CookieTime Values = 8/16/2012 12:34:00 AM
CookieTime = 0
Parsed Date = 946702800000
currTime = 8-18-2012 1345311956215
CookieTime - currTime = NaN

```
document.write('CookieTime Values = ' + reminders[0].reminderdate + ' ' + reminders[0].remindertime + '<br/>'); // = 8/16/2012 12:34:00 AM
var CookieTime = new Date(reminders[0].reminderdate & ' ' & reminders[0].remindertime);
CookieTime = CookieTime.getTime()

document.write('CookieTime = ' + CookieTime + '<br/>'); // = 0
document.write('Parsed Date = ' + Date.parse(CookieTime)  + '<br/>'); // = 946702800000

var currDate = new Date();
var currDate = currDate.getMonth() + 1 + "-" + currDate.getDate() + "-" + currDate.getFullYear();

var currTime = new Date();
currTime = currDate + ' ' + currTime.getTime();
document.write('currTime = ' + currTime + '<br/>'); // = 8-18-2012 1345410601357

document.write('CookieTime - currTime = ' + CookieTime - currTime + '<br/>'); // = NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you have:

```
var CookieTime = new Date('8/16/2012 12:34:00 AM'); // Date {Thu Aug 16 2012 00:34:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)}
console.log(CookieTime.getTime()); // 1345066440000

var currDate = new Date();
var date = currDate.getMonth() + 1 + "-" + currDate.getDate() + "-" + currDate.getFullYear(); // 8-18-2012
var time = currDate.getTime(); // NOW it's 1345314741769
console.log(date + ' ' + time); // 8-18-2012 1345314741769

var difference = CookieTime - currDate;
console.log(difference); // -248301769
```

Now you can check if `difference` is lower zero then the `CookieTime` hasn't passed the current time else - it has.

Comment: One for CookieDate and the other for currDate.

Comment: I asked about currDate and currTime, they have initially the same value

Comment: Okay does this work then? `var currTime = new Date();
  var currTime = currTime.getMonth() + 1 + "-" + currTime.getDate() + "-" + currTime.getFullYear() + ' ' +  + currTime.getHours() + ':' +  + currTime.getMinutes() + ':' +  + currTime.getSeconds();

  document.write('currTime = ' + currTime + '<br/>');`

Comment: made an edit, your code should look like this

P.S. use console.log() for output

Comment: Thank you sooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo MUCH! Oh my head hurts... I'm going to play with this so I really understand it!! Your a big help!

Answer (score 2):

```
if (new Date().getTime() > Date.parse(cookieTime)) {
  console.log('Current datetime > cookie datetime do what you have to');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to separate date and time:

Just subtract (new Date()).getTime()

Comment: When you say no need to seperate date/time do u mean this area? `currTime = currDate + ' ' + currTime.getTime();` change to `currTime = currDate + currTime.getTime();` Like this?

Comment: var now = (new Date()).getTime(), difference = CookieTime - now;

Comment: getTime() returns total ms since midnight 1/1/1970 so it contains both date and time info.